# Классификация слов и словосочетаний

Tags: классификация

Студент-филолог классифицировал некоторые слова и словосочетания русского языка. Вот примеры выражений, попавших в разные группы.

```
1) декабрь, семнадцатый век
2) вторник, полдень
3) прошлое лето, глубокая ночь
4) следующая неделя, расвет

В какую группу должно было попасть словосочетание «второе число»?
а) в 1
б) во 2
в) в 3
г) в 4
д) ни в одну
```

Comment: Какие Вы услеживаете общности?  Что бы могло стать названиями этих категорий?  Исходя из этих названий/общностей, как "второе число" классифицировать?  Что непонятно?  Пожалуйста, сделайте хотя бы минимальное усилие к выполнению своего домашнего задания.

Comment: Pingvin, а на основе каких критерий он классифицировал эти слова и словосочетания и разбил их на группы?

Answer (score 5):

*Друзья, вы же филологи, а не буквоеды, вспоминаем грамматику.*

Все сочетания так или иначе относятся **ко времени**, отвечают на вопрос **"когда?"**

1) декабрь, семнадцатый век - *в декабре, в семнадцатом веке* - **"В"+предложный**.
2) вторник, полдень - *во вторник, в полдень* - **винительный**.
3) прошлое лето, глубокая ночь - *прошлым летом, глубокой ночью* - **творительный**.
4) следующая неделя, рассвет - *на следующей неделе, на рассвете* - **"На"+предложный**.
5) *второго числа* - **родительный**.

Ответ Д. Ни в одну.

//------------

*Pingvin! Огромное спасибо за задачку! Давно тут таких не было изящных. Несите еще!*

upd 11.11.2015
//===================
Pingvin!
Разумеется, можно теоретически рассматривать и другие группы, другие вопросы. Но у нас эти группы **известны по условию**. Ни один другой вопрос, ни одно другое предположение (ну из высказанных и внятно формулируемых по крайней мере) не позволит "рассортировать" выбранные восемь сочетаний по четырем группам именно таким образом. Давали какие-то предположения, я их напрочь не понял, боюсь, что их авторы - тоже не очень.

Вопрос-то стоял именно так. Найти **почему** студент именно такие группы сделал - так чтобы указанные выражения именно в них попадали. а потом уже посмотреть девятое сочетание.

Более полно ответ выглядит так.
***Студент рассортировал сочетания по группам в зависимости от грамматики управления существительным, т.е. требуемого предлога и падежа при ответе на вопрос "Когда?".***

Студент хозяин, вот выбрал он такой вопрос как харектеристическое свойство для отнесения к группам. Моя классификация, какое свойство хочу, то и выбираю. Вот выбрал вопрос "Когда?". А наша задача - угадать, какой именно он вопрос сам себе задавал. Вполне корректно.

> Я согласно с ответом, если поставлен конкретный вопрос -когда произошлого событие? В остальных случаях падежи могут отличаться

И студент согласен, он сам этот вопрос и поставил.

А что с другими вопросами?  "К какому сроку принести контрольную"? К такому-то. Ко второму числу. Да, дательный. Но он тут всегда дательный. Что к декабрю, что к рассвету, что к полудню, что к семнадцатому веку. Нет никаких оснований по этому признаку относить сочетания к разным группам. Аналогично и другие возможные вопросы. Так что нет никакого основания считать, что студент рассуждал подобным образом.

Придумайте другой вопрос (или другое основание) для **именно такого распределения этих восьми сочетаний по таким группам** - я с вами соглашусь сразу. Тут пробовали, но я не осилил. Вряд ли студент был наркоманом.)))

> Две группы с предложным падежом смущают (хоть и с разными предлогами)

Не должно смущать. Именно эти два признака *(вернее тут, наверное,  сказать "требования")* -  предлог и падеж - определяют именное управление *(т.е. управление существительным, прилагательным, местоимением, числительным или группой на их основе)* - студент все-таки филолог, он должен знать такие вещи

Answer (score 0):

"Выражению" самое место в пункте два, где полдень вторника.

Декабрь семнадцатого века отдыхает (без года-то), ночь прошлого лета без месяца - туда же, а рассвету второго числа мешает избыточная следующая неделя.

Comment: непонятно, подробнее можно?

Comment: То есть как непонятно?!

Comment: да никак не понятно. )))

Comment: Есть четыре группы: 1) век с месяцем года; 2) день недели со временем на часах; 3) некое лето с полночью; 4) некая неделя с рассветом. Вариант 2: "Второе число, вторник, полдень". А пункта пять я не видела, когда писала ответ... Но остаюсь при своём понимании  э-э-э... проблемы.

Comment: Что за группы такие? Никогда подобного не встречал. Вы их сами сейчас придумали?

Comment: Если опять непонятно: только в пункте под нумером два логически место числу; все оставшиеся отпадают по причине абсурдности. Мартобря 86 числа (с).

Comment: Группы придумал автор вопроса: "Вот примеры выражений, попавших в разные группы..." Это не Вы? А, вижу, автор - Pingvin. Может, он поймёт? Русее у меня не объясняется.

Comment: Нет. Автор таких групп не придумывал. С чего вы взяли? Это русский язык ему подсказал. Иначе зачем автору надо было объединять "месяц" с "веком"? Ну хорошо, объясните, как вы поняли, какие слова или выражения вообше попадают в такие группы. И каким образом туда попали приведенные слова?

Answer (score 0):

Моё мнение - ни в какую, то есть "Д".

Мотивация: Выражения, примеры которых приведены, все имеют в себе запятые, то есть они - перечисления.  Схемы перечислений, похоже, следующие:

1. Существительное ***зпт*** прилагательное существительное
2. Существительное ***зпт*** существительное
3. Прилагательное существительное ***зпт*** прилагательное существительное
4. Прилагательное существительное ***зпт*** существительное

Словосочетание "второе число" не является перечислением и поэтому не попадает ни в какую группу.

Answer (score 0):

А вот такое предложение: на второе число назначена контрольная. Здесь падеж винительный. 
Behemothus, просьба откомментировать.

Comment: Или еще - принести ко второму числу - дательный падеж

Comment: Вторая группа можно дательный падеж: ко вторнику, к полудню

Comment: Четвертая группа- с рассвета, со следующей недели - родительный

Comment: Прочитайте ещё раз данный behemothusом ответ.  Каким образом использовать "второе число" при ответе на вопрос: "когда?".  Вы ведь не скажете: "на второе число", если Вас спросят: "когда будет контрольная?"

Comment: Я согласно с ответом, если поставлен конкретный вопрос -когда произошлого событие? В остальных случаях падежи могут отличаться

Comment: Могут.  Мы же гадаем, по какому принципу были классифицированы эти фразы.  Согласно догадке behemothusа, это - падежи при вопросе "когда".  Что ещё выдумывать-то?

Comment: Я не выдумываю, а стараюсь со всех сторон рассмотреть вопрос. С логической точки зрения не люблю ответ, ни в одну группу))

Comment: Ну, конечно, Вам же задание сдавать и оценку за него получать...

Comment: Две группы с предложным падежом смущают (хоть и с разными предлогами)

Comment: pingvin, извините, не сразу ответил. Вы сейчас в условии  задачи подменяете ответ и условие. Я дополню ответ сейчас.

Answer (score 0):

Мне задача показалась очень интересной (к сожалению, я ответ прочитала вместе с вопросом), но зато можно было проследить за ходом дискуссии, и это тоже было любопытно: и состав участников (кто может ответить, кому интересно отвечать), и ход рассуждений.

Задача интересна тем, что она имеет две плоскости: грамматическую и семантическую, и ответ надо было искать в грамматике. **Однако грамматическая сторона была замаскирована начальной формой слов и словосочетаний, а семантическая, напротив, выдвинута на первый план** (как ложный след). Поэтому ситуация никак не прояснялась, пока не нашелся **общий ключик - местоимение когда.**

**Именно при ответе на этот вопрос в русском языке задействовано такое количество падежей:** предложный с предлогами В и НА, винительный с предлогом В, творительный и родительный беспредложные. **И можно поставить вопрос: а как различается семантика этих вариантов?**

1) Основное значение **предложного падежа** - это ненаправленность, что отличает его от винительного падежа, причем предлог В просто определяет промежуток времени: в декабре, а предлог НА может дополнительно указывать на неопределенность: на следующей неделе.

2) Основное значение **винительного падежа** - направленность действия, поэтому время указано точно: в полдень.

3) **Творительный падеж** является носителем орудийной семантики, он называет предмет, который придает действию известный вид, образ, форму: глубокой ночью, прошлым летом (называется отрезок времени, на которое приходится действие).

4) Одним из основных значений **родительного падежа** является партитивность - указание на часть предмета, на его границы. Именно временная граница обозначена  сочетанием "второго числа".

И конечно, мои поздравления behemothus, который порадовал нас своим решением этой непростой задачи.